# What will the time complexity of this python program in Big O notation?

Tags: python, pandas, time-complexity, big-o

I find it difficult to calculate the time complexity of this program as it involves a lot of built-in methods. Could anyone please help? Basically the question is to find topper of each subject and 3 overall best performers!

```
from sys import argv
df=pd.read_csv(sys.argv[1])
subjects=['Maths','Biology','Physics','English','Chemistry','Hindi']
total=[]
for column in subjects:
  a=df[column].max()  #finding the maximum value in each column
  b=df.loc[(df[column]==a),['Name']] #locating the corresponding row of the found maximum value
print("Topper in "+column+" is "+re.sub("\[|\]|'","",str(b.values.tolist())))


df['total']=df['Maths']+df['Biology']+df['Physics']+df['Chemistry']+df['Hindi']+df['English']
df_v1=df.sort_values(by=['total'],ascending=False)
print("Best students in this class are: ")
for i in range(3):
 print(str(i+1)+"."+df_v1.iloc[i]['Name'])
```

Input csv file looks something like this:

```
Name  Physics Chemistry Biology Maths Hindi English
Steve  99     1000      100     95    97    85
John    80     90        75     70    100   100
```

Output:

```
  Topper in maths is X
  Topper in physics is y
Overall best students are X,y,z
```

Comment: So you are trying to find the three students with the highest cumulative score over all subjects? Based on a dataframe with students as records and grades for each subject?

Comment: Yes exactly! That's the second part. In the first part, I am supposed to find the toppers of each subject individually.

Comment: Do you have an example of the input data?

Comment: Name  Physics Biology Chemistry Hindi Maths  (Column names) \newline                                                     Thomas   90      100         85             95    100     (values)  \newline                                                                          John          100   70          60             50      90         \newline                                                                     Steve       95         90        85             85      100

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Hi thanks for the suggestion! I have edited it now!

Comment: something like the larger of `O(N*log(N))` where N is the number of rows, due to the sort, or `O(N*M)` where `N` is the number of rows, and `M` is the number of columns

Comment: In any case, this really isn't the pandas way to do things. You probably want something like `df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)` then you can do things with `df.max(axis=0)` or maybe `df.apply('idxmax')`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion mate! This looks a lot easier! @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your for loop goes over all columns for each row => O(row * col) complexity.
2. Calculation of totals does the same => O(row * col)
3. The `sort_values` sorts all values in one column, and usually, sort functions are O(nLog(n)) in theory, so this gives us O(row * Log(row))

All in all, we have O(row * col) + O(row * col) + O(row * log(row) => O(row * col)

So the answer is O(row * col)

**Edit**

If col << row, you might actually get O(row*log(row)). So if the number of columns is finite, it is actually O(row*log(row))